# Best approach join table query

Tags: sql, laravel, postgresql

I'm new to sql. What would be the best practice for joining tables below? So far I try this `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT CONCAT(u.first_name,' ',u.middle_name,' ',u.last_name) AS student FROM users u
LEFT JOIN students s ON s.student_id= u.id
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT(usr.first_name,' ',usr.middle_name,' ',usr.last_name) AS faculty  FROM users usr
LEFT JOIN faculty f ON f.faculty_id= usr.id
```

this is the results:

```
|       student       |   
|---------------------|
| John Doe Garbin     | 
| John Faculty Samson |
| John Staff Thomas   |
```

also the `SELECT SUBQUERY` but did not hit my target results, I also try this approach

```
SELECT CONCAT(u.first_name,' ',u.middle_name,' ',u.last_name) AS faculty, CONCAT(s.first_name,' ',s.middle_name,' ',s.last_name) AS student FROM faculty f
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.id = f.id
LEFT JOIN students AS s ON s.id = u.id
```

but the problem is alias from student is unknown. Much appreciated all answers.

users :

```
| id      |  first_name  | middle_name  | last_name |        email       |  roles  |
|---------|--------------|--------------|-----------|--------------------|---------|
| 1234567 |   John       |  Doe         |  Garbin   | johndoe@gmail.com  | student |
|---------|--------------|--------------|-----------|--------------------|---------|
| 7654321 |   John       |  Faculty     |  Samson   |   john@gmail.com   | faculty |
|---------|--------------|--------------|-----------|--------------------|---------|
| 2222222 |   John       |   Staff      |  Thomas   |   jhon@gmail.com   | faculty |
```

faculty:

```
| faculty_id | other_column |
|------------|--------------|
|  7654321   |  attribute   |
|  2222222   |  attribute   |
```

student:

```
| student_id  |  other_column |
|-------------|---------------|
|  1234567    |  attribute    |
```

My target results:

```
|    student      |       faculty       |   
|-----------------|---------------------|
| John Doe Garbin | John Faculty Samson |
```

Comment: Why did you get `John Faculty Samson` to faculty  column    instead `John       |   Staff      |  Thomas `?

Comment: is there a good reason why john faculty and not john staff?

Comment: actually what I meant on the target results was to display all faculties on faculty column, not only for John Faculty